# If $f(0)=0$ and $\lvert f'(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert, \forall x \in ]0, \infty [$, prove that $f(x)=0, \forall x \gt 0$

Tags: calculus

Let $f: [0, \infty[ \to  \mathbb{R}$ coninuous on $[0, \infty[$ and differentiable on $]0,\infty[$. If $f(0)=0$ and $\lvert f'(x) \rvert \le \lvert f(x) \rvert, \forall x \in ]0, \infty [$, prove that $f(x)=0, \forall x \ge 0$

I started by taking a function $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ and deriving it.
Doing so gives $g'(x)=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x)), \forall x \ge0$. If only $f'(x)=f(x)$ was true, the proof would be done, but what can I do when $ \lvert f'(x) \rvert \lt \lvert f(x) \rvert$?

Answer (score 1):

By FTC
$$
f(x) = \int_0^x f'(s)ds
$$
Take absolute values
$$
|f(x)| = \bigg|\int_0^x f'(s)ds\bigg| \leq \int_0^x|f(s)|ds
$$
By Gronwall Inequality $|f(x)| = 0$.

Comment: I can’t use integrals just yet, but the problem does come with an explanation that it is a form of gronwall’s inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Since the derivative at 0 is 0 and the value of the function is 0, for any  $\epsilon$ we can find a $\delta$ small enough such that for all x within $\delta$ of 0, we have $f(x) \leq \epsilon$. For all of those values of $x$, we also have that the derivative is bounded by $\epsilon$. Now we can repeat the argument over the entire domain of $f$. Then choose $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be assuming that f is differentiable at 0? Which according to the question would be false.

Comment: Ah that's right, then apply continuity at 0 to show that $f(x)$ is close for small $c$, then apply the same argument.