# all functions for which f(x)=f'(x) and f(0)=0

Tags: functions

To prove that no such functions which satisfy the following:

f(x)=f'(x) and f(0)=0

exist or give example if it exists.

Except f(x)=0

Edit: Not a homework problem. I'm trying to solve an integral problem by substitution and this question came to my mind

Comment: Well there's obviously $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, and anything else

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133707/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3876133/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3896897/42969

Comment: Or simply: let $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x),$ then $g'=0$ hence $g(x)=g(0)=0.$

Comment: Are you aware of the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for differential equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f’=f$$
$$f=c_1e^x$$
$$f(0)=c_1e^0=c_1=0$$

Which means $f(x)=0\cdot e^x,\enspace i.e.\enspace f(x)=0$

Therefore, no such function will satisfy the condition expect $f(x)=0$.